# Summing elements of a 1D array

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I'm trying to add the elements of a Linear array using code as below, but the output I'm getting is equal to the number of elements in the array. I cant seem to find the reason why.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ar[i] = scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
        sum += ar[i];  
    }
```

Output:- The number of elements in the array (n), which is incorrect.

Consequently, when I try `ar[i] != scanf("%d",&ar[i]);` instead of above, it gives correct output. Any help would be thanked for.

Comment: "_The number of elements in the array (n), which is incorrect._" - How so?

Comment: `scanf()` : On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value read is overwritten by the number of data read because you are assigning the return value of `scanf()` to `ar[i]`. Stop the assignment and use the value for checking if reading succeeds.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(scanf("%d",&ar[i]) != 1)
            {
                /* handle error */
            }
        sum += ar[i];  
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou, but what happens when I use 
ar[i] != scanf("%d",&ar[i]); in the loop body ? It produces the correct sum.

Comment: @CarlZimmer `ar[i] != scanf("%d",&ar[i]);` does a meaningless comparision whose result is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
ar[i] = scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
```

Just change to:

```
scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
```

the return from scanf should be 1
So, it is changing the value of ar[i] after the scanf to 1. Hence, the sum being the number of elements.

Comment: The answer by @MikeCAT is better since it takes into account error handling for when the result of scanf != 1 !!!